# Why does my if statement in my while loop only execute in debugging?

Tags: java, user-interface, debugging, intellij-idea

So I am making a tic-tac-toe game and I'm using a GUI made with JButtons in IntelliJ. Here is my current code for detecting when a button is pressed and marking it with an `X` or an `O`.

```
public static void taketurn(){
    Boolean gamerunning = true;
    while(gamerunning){
        if(button1.getModel().isPressed()) {
            button1.setText("X");
            gamerunning = false;
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, when running the code, it creates the UI all fine, but clicking on the button has no effect. However, when I go into debugging and but a break at `button1.setText("X")` and then step forward from there, it correctly executes the code and an `X` appears. Why does this only work in debugging with breaks and not normal run?

Comment: It's probably being cleared by other code before you have a chance to see it.

Comment: This isn't a good way to intercept button presses. Please take a look at the `ActionListener` class instead.

Comment: Alright, Ill look into that, thanks.

Comment: @WillB Did my solution satisfactorily answer your question? If so, could you please select it as the chosen answer?

Comment: @BrandonLaidig Yes, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What might be happening is when running full speed the if isn't executing before the while loop starts over again. Have you considered using an actionListener on the buttons instead?
Try something like this when creating your buttons

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //logic here to add X or O
        }
}});
```

Then, you shouldn't need to worry about running through a loop to wait for the user to select. Any time they press the button, your logic will handle adding the X or O

Answer (score 1):

I think using an ActionListener class is a good idea here. 
You can make your own ActionListener implementation without having to use anonymous classes, like this:

```
class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //The stuff you want to do when the button is pressed
    }

}
```

Then you can make a new instance of this class whenever you need it, and add it to your JButton with the addActionListener(ActionListener l) function.

```
MyJButton.addActionListener(new MyActionListener());
```